# firestore security rules for nested documents

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have Two collections in firestore

1. userTbl
2. instituteTbl

In userTbl, I have store schoolid of specific user in schoolid field.
Now, I want that loggedin user should able to get access of data of there schoolid only.

***What I Tried***

```
match /instituteTbl/{userTbl/userID/schoolid}/{document=**}{
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
```

***But Its not working, Please help me with this***

Screenshot of userTbl Data structure
[image: Screenshot of userTbl Data structure]
Screenshot of instituteTbl Data structure
[[image: Screenshot of instituteTbl Data structure]]

Comment: Can you share your code so we can see what query you are running?

Comment: Showing your code is required because we can't see if your query matches your rules.  We should be able to duplicate the behavior you're seeing with the information you provide.